# How to properly load photos with Node and Webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Should I be loading photos in node by importing relative paths or by referencing the file URL, and how do you properly load photos from their relative path?

Currently I'm serving static files with express:

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
```

And loading photos by referencing file URLs:

```
  <img src='/images/tom.jpg'/>
```

I have a webpack configuration set up to use file-loader on (png|jpg|gif), and the webpack docs say, that with file-loader, you can import photos from relative paths (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx):

```
import img from './file.png'
```

With this configuration (this is the config I'm using):

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I try to import an image from it's relative path:

```
//import   
import img from '../../public/images/tom.jpg';

//render
<img src={img}/>
```

I receive this error:

> /Users/ryan/Desktop/Df/Coding/ryanchacon.io/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/ryan/Desktop/Df/Coding/ryanchacon.io/public/images/tom.jpg:
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>
> > 1 | ����

But if I emit the 'import from relative path', start my server, and then add the relative import back, the image will load from its relative path. However, if I restart my server, the error throws again.

So instead I'm referencing the file URL to get around this error, but I'm not sure how I should properly load files from their relative path with my webpack/node configuration.

Currently, I'm running node v8.6.0, webpack v3.6.0, express v4.15.4, file-loader v1.1.5, and react v16.0.0.

Comment: How are you running your server? Meaning, are you running bundled code? Reminder: Node.js by itself does not know how to import image files (or any other non-JS files for that matter).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using webpack to bundle the code into /bundle.js and throwing that in a script tag in the html. I created a bare-minimum project based off the dependencies my app uses to test file-loader. This mimics my setup and produces the same error: https://github.com/Always-Sunny/bare-minimum/tree/fileloader

Comment: So the question is, what is the scenario that your node.js server even get the jpg import statement, as it is client code

Comment: Through express; using it to render a template engine (ejs) which react hooks onto via the root id. Also using it to serve static files via the public folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your server.js file, you're using server side rendering (which is awesome): `ReactDOMServer.renderToString( <App /> )`. The `App` component rendered on the server side is imported via the `import App from './src/App';` statement. In the App.js file you have the JPG import statement: `import img from '../public/hermes.jpg';`.

Please notice that **in this context, your node.js is not aware of any webpack bundle in your project**, and node actually tries to import the `'../public/hermes.jpg'` file, which causes the error you're facing (node can only load JS modules).

So the question is, in fact, how to use `file-loader` in a universal/isomorphic manner. You can take a look at this example project: https://github.com/webpack/react-webpack-server-side-example that shows a webpack configuration for both the server and the client code. Theoretically, if you bundle your server code via webpack, when you run it, the JPG import statement would already be processed by the file loader and should not cause any problem. I have to admit that personally I do not think bundling server code is a good idea (bundling solves client side issues that are not really relevant on the server side).

If you insist using `file-loader` and bundling your image files into your client code, using server side webpack might be a good solution for you. If not, you can simply load the images from the `/public` folder.

For what it's worth, I believe that loading the images by using URLs is not only simpler, but also faster - the browser will download your lighter JS bundle (it's lighter because it does not contain encoded image files) and your code will start running earlier on, downloading the images from HTTP in a parallel, asynchronous manner.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Gilad. I was wondering if you'd take a look at the issue I posted on file-loaders GitHub: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/210 When I posted it, the moderator, cloned my repo, updated file-loader, and got the relative import working in a second, but when I did the same, I still received an error. So I'm still stuck with some underlying problem. Even if it is the server rendering causing the error, someone else was able to take my code, and get it working without changing anything but updating a dependency, and I'm stumped.

Comment: Again, in my opinion this issue has nothing to do with `file-loader`, because the code your node.js is running is not aware of `file-loader` nor webpack. I am guessing there was some kind of misunderstanding with the moderator, because there is not reason that the same code will behave differently on two environments.